# node_manager_fkie rosrun node_manager package not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After pulling from git and doing an apparently successful catkin_make (and catkin_make install) I can't seem to run node_manager!  When I do

rosrun node_manager_fkie node_manager

on Indigo, I get error: package 'node_manager_fkie' not found.

Any ideas about what the problem might be?   Any other ROS parameter server GUIs you would recommend?

Thanks!

Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195299/node_manager_fkie-rosrun-node_manager-package-not-found/) by [steve](https://answers.ros.org/users/20486/steve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at your environment variables? (That was my issue)

---

Originally posted by [kensley](https://answers.ros.org/users/20854/kensley/) with karma: 81 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0